# Is there a difference in meaning between "criticism of the police" and "THE criticism of the police"

Tags: articles, definite-article

A of B

consideration of B

use of B

destruction of B

B is an object of A

but in some cases, B becomes a subject: the arrival of the police (the police arrives)

So I am asking about what the difference is between:

criticism of the police (=sb criticizes the police?)

and

the criticism of the police (=police criticizes sth?)

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking. In English, most words and phrases can have different meanings in different contexts. Providing complete sentences as examples would be helpful.

Comment: Adding an article doesn’t make criticism belong to the police. *The criticism of the police only got worse after the second incident.* The police are still being criticized in that sentence. There are some good answers around here dealing with “the boy’s book” versus “the book of the boy” that might be helpful, but I haven’t been able to find them quickly.